# Dynamics Crm insert image in a view

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I am using Dynamics 365 V9.
The view has a field that contains the url of an image. I would like to show in every line of the view, instead of the url, the image itself. Is it possible? Do I need to build a web resource for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamics allows us to show images in views. Please see the article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customize/display-custom-icons-instead

Basically, you have to add a web resource(JS) which should contain a logic to show the particular image. The image must be uploaded in CRM. 
Hope it helps.